# How to know when a 'dd' command has been completed?

Tags: dd

My system is running the command `sudo dd if=/home/vico/file.iso of=/dev/sdb1`, it returns control inmediately, but the transfer takes a while. How to know that the whole process has ended?

Comment: Run `sync`? It's not a guarantee that there will be no new dirty pages shortly after the `sync` though..

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1**

Rewrite your command like this

```
sudo dd if=/home/vico/file.iso of=/dev/sdb1 status=progress
```

Sample output:

```
462858752 bytes (463 MB, 441 MiB) copied, 38 s, 12,2 MB/s
```

`dd` in GNU Coreutils 8.24 (Ubuntu 16.04 and newer) have this `status` option to display progress.

**Method 2**

Install `pv`

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

Some examples

```
pv -n /dev/urandom | dd of=/dev/null
pv -tpreb source.iso | dd of=/dev/BLABLA bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dd-command-show-progress-while-coping/)

Comment: It works nicely, Thx, Luka!